# Insert column from another table while matching emails in both tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert phone number field from orders table into users table, while matching orders.Email field = users.Email field.

This is what I have so far but the `WHERE` clause is not working:

```
INSERT INTO users (Phone)  
SELECT Billing_Phone
  FROM orders
WHERE users.Email = orders.Email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify rows, you use `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.

```
UPDATE users AS u
JOIN orders AS o ON u.Email = o.Email
SET u.Phone = o.Billing_Phone
```

Comment: Duh, what was I think about.  Thanks